# Atualizar e manter código da atualização quando ele se repetir

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Fiz essa atualização:

```
declare
@rx_num varchar(20),
@id_oit_max int,
@id_exm_rea int,
@id_xfc_novo int,
@id_xfc int = 0

declare oit_cur cursor
for
select  pl.rx_num, er.id_exm_rea, er.id_xfc from t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl
inner join T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO er on pl.ID_XFC = er.ID_XFC and pl.RX_NUM = er.NO_RX

open oit_cur
fetch next from oit_cur into @rx_num, @id_exm_rea, @id_xfc_novo

select @id_oit_max = max(id_oit) from t_cmo_oit1980

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

    if @id_xfc <> @id_xfc_novo
        set @id_oit_max = @id_oit_max + 1

    update t_cmo_planilha_leitura set id_oit = @id_oit_max
    where rx_num = @rx_num

    set @id_xfc = (select er.id_xfc from t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl
    inner join T_CMO_EXAME_REALIZADO er on pl.ID_XFC = er.ID_XFC and pl.RX_NUM = er.NO_RX
    where er.id_xfc = @id_xfc_novo)

    fetch next from oit_cur into @rx_num, @id_exm_rea, @id_xfc_novo
end

close oit_cur
deallocate oit_cur
```

Qual a leitura disso: Eu tenho duas variáveis importantes, que são `@id_xfc_novo` e `@id_xfc`. Esse bloco a intenção é a seguinte: Entro com o novo com valor zero(0). E quando eu faço a comparação, o @id_xfc vai ter um valor diferente de zero e na comparação que faço, retorna true, e incrmento a variável e preencho no meu UPD. Aí, após o UPD, eu seto a variável @id_xfc para pegar o o valor atual do campo. E logo após, dou um fetch next e a variável Novo, teoricamente virá com outro valor ou não. Caso venha com outro valor, o if retorna true e incremento a outra var e uso no UPD, caso seja false(Novo com mesmo valor que a velha), não incremento e a var fica com o valor antigo, repetindo no UPD o mesmo valor(desejado). Isso nã está acontecendo, ou seja, a var `@id_oit_max` está sempre incrementando, como se se a condição fosse sempre verdadeira e não é. Tenho alguns registros repetidos. O que tá errado na minha lógica?

Observei que dá um erro de vez em quando na subquery e retorna dessa forma. Coloquei um print pra ver está vindo isso:

> > (1 linha(s) afetadas) Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 32
> >     Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> >     subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> >     an expression.
>
> velho: 232  novo: 243
>
> > (1 linha(s) afetadas) Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 32
> >     Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> >     subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> >     an expression.
>
> velho: 232  novo: 243
>
> > (1 linha(s) afetadas) Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 32
> >     Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> >     subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> >     an expression.
>
> velho: 232  novo: 243
>
> > (1 linha(s) afetadas) Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 32
> >     Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> >     subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> >     an expression.
>
> velho: 232  novo: 243

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi colocando um top 1, como o colega Ismael me havia dito. Coloquei na subquery que está dentro do while e resolveu. Valeu a todos.